# How to get the formatted number with country code when disabledFormatting is false

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I am developing a laravel project with vue js components.
I am using EducationLink/vue-tel-input for phone input.
I don't want to display the formatted number in input field. so I add prop `:disabledFormatting` as `true`. but I want the formatted number. How can I get it?? Please help me.

I use `onInput` function as

```
onInput(formattedNumber, { number, isValid, country, international }) {
    this.phone.number = number;
    this.phone.isValid = isValid;
    this.phone.country = country && country.name;
    this.phone.formattedNumber = formattedNumber;
},
```

But when I console `this.phone.formattedNumber` it will give the normal number. I want a number like  +91 1234 567 890 this but i got 1234567890.
I am using `"vue-tel-input": "^3.0.0"`

Answer (score 0):

> Disable formatting the phone number in the input, the formatted result still be accessible by formattedNumber returned from onInput event

I found this from the document of that package. Hope it will help

Comment: i also saw it. but it doesnot working. `this.phone.formattedNumber = formattedNumber;` i used it like this

Comment: that's event not property, <vue-tel-input @input="onInput" />

Comment: `<vue-tel-input :enabledCountryCode="phone_attributes.enabledCountryCode" 
                                                :disabledFormatting="phone_attributes.disabledFormatting" 
                                                :inputClasses="phone_attributes.class" 
                                                :name="phone_attributes.name"
                                                :placeholder="phone_attributes.placeholder" @input="onInput">                            
                                            </vue-tel-input>` This is the code i used

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/vue-template-gzzip
check this console, you'll see formartted input after you enter full phone number

Comment: but in the iput field it shows the formatted number. I want the un formatted nmber in input field and formatted number in a vue variable

Comment: seems like the disabledFormatting is not working at all. It still format when I set it true.